# Obtain a set of numbers from a sequence of arrays of strings in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, string

I have an array of strings which is as follows

```
b=["yesterday: 40", "today: 20", "change: +3", "changes_2: 10.00%", "high: 30", "low: 20"]
```

How would I obtain the set of values 40,20,+3, 10.00%, 30 and 20 from that array

I've done

```
 c = b.map {|n| n.split(" ")}
```

That returns

```
 [["yesterday:", "40"], ["today:", "20"], ["change:", "+3"], ["changes_2:", "10.00%"], ["high:", "30"], ["low:", "20"]]
```

Comment: Consider using `map` on the array, then using `String#split` on each of the component strings in the map block to extract what you want.

Comment: You're close! As you can see, `String#split` returns an array, so you can select a particular index of it to return from the `map` block, rather than just aggregating all the arrays returned from `split`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald ... I have mapped and split it as you said. How do I go about extracting the values now, I did c.first.last and got 40, but when I did d= c.each{|x| x.last} I'm still getting the same array returned by c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just index the `split` array before returning it in the block:

```
> c = b.map {|n| n.split(": ")[1]}
=> ["40", "20", "+3", "10.00%", "30", "20"]
```

Comment: I'd use `.last` instead of the index, but that's personal preference.