# Ruby Extracting an array of numerical data from a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, string

I have an app that fetches a string of content with the following format from a feed

```
b="yesterday: 136.00, current: *143.00*, change: *+7.00*, change_2: *5.15%*, high: 143.00, low: 143.00"
```

At irregular intervals the feed may return a date in this format 2014/08/15 instead of a number such that

```
b="yesterday: 2014/12/02, current: *143.00*, change: *+7.00*, change_2: *5.15%*, high: 143.00, low: 143.00"
```

However this date maybe returned in any category e.g. "change_2: 2013/1/21" or even "high: 2014/11/23" in a random format.

The feed may also return comma separated values instead of a decimal but in reality it is supposed to be a decimal value e.g.

```
b="yesterday: 136,00, current: *143.00*, change: *+7.00*, change_2: *5,15%*, high: 143.00, low: 143.00"
```

The feed may also return the following:

```
b="yesterday: 2014/02/12, current: *143,00*, change: *+7.00*, change_2: *5.15%*, high: 143.00, low: 143.00"
```

Note that a date and a comma separated value has been returned and the order in which the stream returns this data is totally random.

How can I check to ensure the cleaniness of data that is being passed into  to ensure comma's in vales are turned into decimal points e.g. 23,12 to 23.13 and any dates returned are replaced by the value 0

This question is a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505649/obtain-a-set-of-numbers-from-a-sequence-of-arrays-of-strings-in-ruby) posted by a colleague

The first answer by aelor returns the following when I have a date as the first value which is okay:

```
 b = ["yesterday: 0", "current: *143.00*", "change: *+7.00*", "change_2: *5.15%*", "high: 143.00", "low: 143.00"]
```

So then I did

```
c = b.split(". ")
d = c.map{ |x| x.scan(/[\d\.-]+/)[0] }.map(&:to_f)
```

However d returns

```
[0.0, 143.0, 7.0, 2.0, 143.0, 143.0]
```

Instead of

```
[0.0, 143.0, 7.0, 5.15, 143.0, 143.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this :

```
b="yesterday: 2014/02/12, current: *143,00*, change: *+7.00*, change_2: *5.15%*, high: 143.00, low: 143.00"
anydate = b.scan(/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/)
if !anydate.empty?
  anydate.each {|s| b = b.gsub(s,'0').gsub(",",".")}
else
  b = b.gsub(",",".")
end
```

check value of `b`

```
"yesterday: 0. current: *143.00*. change: *+7.00*. change_2: *5.15%*. high: 143.00. low: 143.00"
```

Comment: Your answer works fine in extracting the data which is why I've marked the question closed. But how can I the parse the data to obtain the actual data in an array as I've tried to do in my edit?

Answer (score 0):

If there are definitely spaces following the delimiting commas, first of all you are to eliminate commas playing role of decimal separator:

```
s = "yesterday: 136,00, current: *143.00*, change: *+7.00*, " + \
    "change_2: *5,15%*, high: 143.00, low: 143.00"

s.gsub! /,(?=\S)/, '.'
```

Now let’s get rid of dates:

```
s.gsub! /(:\D*)(\d{2,4}[\-\/]\d{2,4}[\-\/]\d{2,4})(?=\D)/, $1+'0'
```

Here you go.

Comment: I just run the last method on irb and it return an  error ** NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClas **

Comment: I used this dataset s ="yesterday: 136.00, current: *143.00*, change: *+7.00*, change_2: *5.15%*, high: 143.00, low: 143.00"